Dismiss Task Dialog Copied Central Model Revit 2023 with Visual Studio
I am trying to close a specific Dialogue which pops when opening copied or downloaded Revit Models. Currently working in Revit 2023 and Visual Studio 2022. I need to automatically dismiss this dialog when I launch the models through Visual Studio, to be able to proceed with other codes that would allow me to automate tasks.

I have looked at some examples to deal with this issue but when I build solution and run the code (which opens the model I need opened through giving it as argument and Revit.exe as application) it does nothing when the model is opened and the dialog above appears. Currently using .Net.4.8 and the added references are as below.

The code I am trying to work is as below.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events;


[TransactionAttribute(TransactionMode.Manual)]

public class RevitCommand : IExternalCommand

{
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData,
      ref string messages, ElementSet elements)

    {
        UIApplication app = commandData.Application;
        Document doc = app.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

        Transaction trans = new Transaction(doc);
        trans.Start("testComamnd");
        app.DialogBoxShowing += new    EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events.DialogBoxShowingEventArgs>(app_DialogBoxShowing);
        trans.Commit();
        return Result.Succeeded;

    }
    public void app_DialogBoxShowing(Object sender, DialogBoxShowingEventArgs args)

    {

        switch (args)
        {
            case TaskDialogShowingEventArgs args2:
                if (args2.DialogId == "TaskDialog_Copied_Central_Model")
                    args2.OverrideResult(1002);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

    }

}

Additionally, here are the URL I took example of trying to work this solution.
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2013/06/dismiss-the-dialog-when-opening-a-copied-central-model-file.html
https://archi-lab.net/dismissing-revit-pop-ups-the-easy-and-not-so-easy-ways/
